# How to pass variable from Botframework Composer to custom action?

Tags: c#, botframework, parameter-passing, schema, bot-framework-composer

I want to pass a value that comes from user input to a custom action. The value is stored in the `user.age` property but in the argument field of the custom action in composer you can not enter variable names, the input fields do only accept `int` values

How can I pass `user.age` to the `MultiplyDialog` custom action?

[I tried the MultiplyDialog example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-add-custom-action?tabs=csharp#about-the-example-custom-action)

[image]

`MultiplyDialog.schema`

```
  ...
  "arg1": {
             "$ref": "schema:#/definitions/integerExpression",
             "title": "Arg1",
             "description": "Value from callers memory to use as arg 1"
       }
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here steps how to get the values from the user ( If use the "user.age" also it should work)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was just missing the `=` statement.